# Avoid overlapping text in html

Tags: python, html, folium

[image]

[image]

I want to put text in that coordinate.
But it's overlapping as shown in the figure.
Is there a code that doesn't overlap?
(The language may be awkward by turning the translator.)

I'm attaching the code below.

How do I transform the icon_size and icon_anchor? Or if there is another code that I don't know, please introduce it.

```
import folium
from folium.features import DivIcon

m = folium.Map(location=[gpsLati, gpsLong], zoom_start=16)

for i in range(len(testtest2)):
    folium.CircleMarker([testtest2.iloc[i][2], testtest2.iloc[i][3]],
                        color = 'black',
                        #fill_color = 'black',
                        ).add_to(m)

for i in range(len(testtest2)):
    folium.map.Marker(
        # 위경도 위치
        [testtest2.iloc[i][2], testtest2.iloc[i][3]],  

        # DivIcon 을 사용
        # html 태그를 이용해서 text를 올릴 수 있음
        icon=DivIcon(
            # icon px 사이즈
            icon_size=(0, 0),
            # icon 좌 상단 위치 설정
            icon_anchor=(0, 0),
            # html 형식으로 text 추가
            # div 태그 안에 style 형식 추가
            html='<div\
                    style="\
                        font-size: 1.2rem;\
                        color: black;\
                        background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);\
                        width:120px;\
                        text-align:center;\
                        margin:0px;\
                        position : static;\
                    "><b>' + testtest2['routeno'][i] + '</b></div>')).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: What behavior do you want? Do you want all the text to show? Or cut off the text where the cell ends?

Comment: @Andrew There are two original images. I have attached another new image. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Try looking into the Intersection Observer browser API. I believe that should solve your problem